# Flutter. Throw widget after dragging

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have been searching around for days in the jungle of widgets, trying to figure out which widget suits my purpose best.

What I have done so far: I have a Positioned widget with a listener, that I can drag around in a Stack with onPointerMove.

What I want to achieve is the following:
If I move my finger a bit faster and at some point let go, I would like to have the widget to continue with the given speed (with some friction) and direction (x,y) until it reaches some point.

Im a iOS developer and did this in Swift, but have I reached a point where I met the limit of Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has a Draggable widget which contains velocity in the onDragEnd event. You might use this and some basic animation to fling the widget using physics. Check out the Cookbook on the Flutter API site.